# Won't look for files in the correct location, instead it looks in the \source\repos\<project> folder

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# program in VS2017 that will read a file that is located in a sub folder of the C:\Program Files folder. When I try to start the application, I get an error saying it can't locate the file in `C:\Users\<loginname>\source\repos\<solutionname>\bin\debug\\<folder name that contains the file>`. In the code, it stops at the `foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file)` saying it can't locate the file with an error message stating

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\Username>\source\repos\NewApp\NewApp\bin\Debug\SubDirectory'."

It should be reading the file from `"C:\Program Files\MyApp\SubDirectory\"`
In prior versions of Visual Studio, this worked as expected, but this only occurred in VS 2017.
The code I have is below:

```
string[] FileDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files\"+"\MyApp\"));
foreach (string dir in SubDirs)
{
    string file = Path.GetFileName(dir);
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file))
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("StartText"))
        {
            string TextToAdd = line;

            ListBox.Items.Add(TextToAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried replacing the hard-coded Program files directory with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) and it instead says it can't find the folder under the Program Files (X86) directory:

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\"

It should be looking in the C:\Program Files folder, not the C:\Program Files (x86) folder.
(BTW, it is Win 10 64 bit OS)

Comment: Your string concatenation syntax is off: Is MyApp a variable?

Comment: `Program Files` is a [SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) is not used that way.

Comment: Yes, if you want to refer to program files, you can use **%programfiles%**. The literal **programfiles** probably doesn't exist on the system.

Comment: It does the same thing either way. I was typing the code quickly for this posting. It should have read "C:\Program Files\" Also, if I change it to a different path, for example "D:\TestFolder\" it still does the same thing. The "MyApp" is the actual folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Program Files` is a [SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to reference it using:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

The actual Path returned might be "`C:\Program Files`" or "`C:\Program Files (x86)`", depending on the current project configuration.
If targeting `x86` or if `Prefer 32-bit` is enabled, the Path returned is "`C:\Program Files (x86)`".

[Path.Combine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) links Path segments in the form of strings, which you provide separated by a comma or as a string array:

```
Path.Combine("[Part1]", "[Part2]")
```

The result is something like this:

```
string MyPath = "[SomeDirectoryName-Possibly-Without-Leading-BackSlash]";
string[] FileDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(
                    Path.Combine(
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), 
                        MyPath));
```

Comment: I did exactly that:


    string[] FileDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)"+"\MyApp\"));

Comment: @Tornado726  Nope. Give it another look. That "+"\MyApp\" is not correct. You have to separate the segments with a **comma**.

Comment: Adding the comma instead of the plus makes VS think it is a UNC path.
EDIT: It was a different issue making VS link it was a UNC path.

Comment: @Tornado726  No, it doesn't. Have you run the code I posted? Try using as `MyPath` an existing Directory in "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Program Files (x86)" (depending on your active configuration). You'll see that it returns all the Subdirectories in that path.

Comment: Jimi, your code did fix the original issue, but now the issue now is that I need it to look in the C:\Program Files\MyApp folder, not the C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp folder.

Comment: @Tornado726  See the edit. If you are targeting `x86` or if `Prefer 32-bit` is active, the path will be "C:\Program Files (x86)". If you don't want this, modify your project configuration as required.